# О пунктуации. Что поставить: кавычки, двоеточие, тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*Запишите меня Иван Иванов*. (Не обращение, а просят так записаться.)

Какие знаки нужны в предложении?

Answer (score 1):

1) Я могу предложить совсем простой вариант:

***Запишите меня (так): Иван Иванов.***

Двоеточие пояснительное, обозначает паузу.  Ударение может падать на первое или второе слово.

Запишите менЯ: Иван Иванов.  (Я хочу записаться).

ЗапишИте меня: Иван Иванов. (Я решил записаться).

2) **Кавычки** мне кажутся сомнительными (непонятно, что они обозначают).

Answer (score 0):

Нужны ***кавычки:***

> *Запишите меня "Иван Иванов".*

Я бы, правда, сказал в творительном падеже:

> *Запишите меня Иваном Ивановым.*

***Убрал кавычки.*** Видимо, действительно, правильно без них при падежном согласовании. Не подумал хорошо сначала!

Но в современном языке, насколько я понимаю, правильно и так, как у Вас.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже так думала!

Answer (score 0):

А вот здесь категорически не соглашусь с Артёмом. Первый вариант действительно уместен, но не второй. Сейчас всё объясню:

1. **Запишите меня "Иванов Иван".** 
   Да, данный вариант вполне уместен. Сам не раз встречался с такими конструкциями. Чтобы проверить постановку кавычек, замените имя собственное на нарицательное, например на "уничтожитель частной собственности" (а вот насчёт того, с какой буквы: большой или маленькой, — написать данное сочетание), где кавычки будут более явными. С чем связана постановка кавычек? Вот тут есть неразрывная связь со следующим примером. На мой взгляд, это зависит от падежа, в котором употреблено данное сочетание. Для последующего объяснения изменю пример:

*Назовите* **меня "уничтожитель частной собственности".**

**Важно**: имя собственное было намеренно убрано, так как уже "приелось" к глаголу "называть (назвать)".

Здесь, если сравнивать, со следующим примером (смотреть ниже), различаются падежи **именной части СИС**. Как известно, употребление именительного падежа в данном случае возможно только в **настоящем времени, обозначающим состояние**. Например:

**Я (кто есть?) учитель.**

Если попробуйте поставить данное сочетание в другие временные формы, даже изменив глагол-связку, форме именительного падежа будет неуместной. В свою очередь, наш пример является своеобразным исключением. И, собственно, кавычки тут стоят из-за нежелательной, но уместной падежной формы.

2. **Запишите (*назовите*, чтобы было проще) меня Иваном.**

Здесь же согласование соблюдено стандартно, поэтому никаких кавычек нет.

3. **Запишите меня (*моё имя*, чтобы было проще, но тогда будет "Иван") — Ивана.**

Это же не относится непосредственно к теме вопроса, но имеет место быть. В данном случае "Ивана" — приложение, стоящее в соответствующей падежной форме.

Надеюсь, правильно всё объяснил.

**UPD1**: Артём, подправь, пожалуйста, ошибки в **словах**, если такие имеются, а то мой словарь так хочет что-нибудь "исправить".

**UPD2**: Ох, не отвертеться мне теперь от ответов.